# adUnitId is not showing google banner ads in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement google ads through admob_flutter package, created adunitId through admob account. but these adUnitId are not showing ads.
when I'm using ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716 this adUnitId then it is showing test ads on google ad.
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:admob_flutter/admob_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GoogleAdBanner extends StatefulWidget {
  GoogleAdBanner(this.size);

  final AdmobBannerSize size;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => BannerAdState();
}

class BannerAdState extends State<GoogleAdBanner> {
  AdmobBanner _bannerAd;
  final Completer<AdmobBanner> bannerCompleter = Completer<AdmobBanner>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Admob.requestTrackingAuthorization();
  }

  String getBannerAdUnitId() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-7282911616152886/6377817226';
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'ca-app-pub-7282911616152886/8046122111';
    }
    return null;
  }

  void handleEvent(
      AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args, String adType) {
    switch (event) {
      case AdmobAdEvent.loaded:
        print('New Admob $adType Ad loaded!');
        break;
      case AdmobAdEvent.opened:
        print('Admob $adType Ad opened!');
        break;
      case AdmobAdEvent.closed:
        print('Admob $adType Ad closed!');
        break;
      case AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad:
        print('Admob $adType failed to load. :(');
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdmobBanner(
      adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(), //'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
      adSize: widget.size,
      listener: (AdmobAdEvent event,
          Map<String, dynamic> args) {
        handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner');
      },
      onBannerCreated: (AdmobBannerController controller) {},
    );
  }
}


using it as
GoogleAdBanner(AdmobBannerSize.LARGE_BANNER)
```

Please help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Real ads are displayed only when there are enough number of requests. The inventory is empty till the threshold has reached. If you are able to see the test ads you can be assured that the implementation is right. Make sure you change the ad app id in manifest and info.plist and add the right ad unit ad in ad request before release.

Answer (score 0):

```
use getBannerAdUnitId() like this:-    
String get BannerAdUnitId(){
```

//body
}

adUnitId: BannerAdUnitId(),

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).